# Match "Helvetica Neue" in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am currently using Helvetica Neue on a website that I am developing. Over the past few months, I have noticed that the Helvetica Neue font renders extremely bold in Google Chrome. When viewing the same site in Firefox, everything looks much better, and as expected.

Here's a comparison screenshot for reference:

[image]

The CSS rule for this portion is fairly straightforward:

```
#top-bar {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#top-bar a {
    color: #eee;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the font looks so different in the two browsers? It almost looks like Chrome is rendering a heavier font weight, even though `font-weight: normal` has no effect. This is not unique to this site, either. Any site (including Bootstrap Docs) that uses Helvetica Neue suffers this on my PC (and others running Chrome). Everything looks fine on a Mac.

Is there a solution? Some technique to mimic FF's rendering of the font in Chrome, for example?

Comment: Helvetica Neue is known to render poorly on Windows, regardless of browser.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't explain why it renders better in FF on Windows. My question is how to match FF's rendering in Chrome, I suppose.

Comment: Helvetica Neue is not available in most computers. If you are serving it via `@font-face`, you should describe this and identify the source of the font and the font files.

Comment: This is not being served by `@font-face`. Please see the font precedence defined. The question relates to computers that have the font installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Firefox supports the hardware-accelerated DirectWrite API (part of Direct2D) to render fonts and Chrome doesn't. See for example:

- [Chrome Issue 25541](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25541)
- [Chrome Issue 124406](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124406)

Even if you switch off hardware acceleration in Firefox, the results are different because both browsers use different font rendering backends.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I guess it's a sit and wait issue then.